# Optimization of difference of two convex function.

Tags: optimization

Suppose we have to minimize a function $f(X,Y)-g(X,Y)$, where both the functions are convex. How can this be solved in matlab? Is there any tool to solve this in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of optimization functions in Matlab. Which to choose depends on the functions $f$ and $g$. For example, you can try fminunc, especially if you know first or second derivatives, or fminsearch for a derivative-free method.

However, note that the difference of convex function is not in general a convex function, so you can get stuck in local minimum.

Comment: Sir when X is a matrix and Y is some column matrix then how it can be fit using fminsearch..

Comment: X and Y can be treat as one big vector of unknowns. However, it will be extremely slow without derivatives.

Comment: use reshape() function to convert matrix to vector and back vector to matrix.

Comment: suppose $f(X,Y)=|l*X*h|^2/(Y(1,:)+0.01)$, then how it can be written using fminsearch . will you help me in writing the code for this?

Comment: Sorry sir but unable to understand..